# managing sortable divs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made some sort able divs in my code, let me show you the code first!

```js
$("#right-panel #images-section #box-section").sortable({
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: "images-placeholder",
  containment: "document",
});
```

```css
#right-panel #images-section {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

#right-panel #images-section h4,
#right-panel #images-section h5 {
  color: #687182;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#right-panel #images-section h5 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 650px;
}

#right-panel #images-section #box-section {
  margin-top: 70px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#right-panel #images-section #box-section .images {
  flex-basis: 28%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 305px;
  border: 1px solid #d82020;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images-placeholder {
  border: 8px dashed gray;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 305px;
  flex-basis: 28%;
  background-color: white;
}

#right-panel #images-section #box-section .images .div-count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#right-panel #images-section #box-section .images .div-count h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #687182;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#right-panel #images-section #box-section #plus {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#right-panel #images-section #box-section #plus h6 {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="right-panel">
  <div id="images-section">

    <div id="box-section">


      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="1">01</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images" id="dosra">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="2">02</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="3">03</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="4">04</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="5">05</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="6">06</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="7">07</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="div-count">
          <h6 sequence-id="8">08</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what is happening right now is when I drag to another div I have to move all the way to the end of current div to make the divs move what I want is to reduce the distance e.g when I start to move a div I want to to shift the next div when I reach 50% with of the div. please try to drag and drop somewhere you might notice the issue through the placeholder css!

Any help?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuo6agy7/4/)

Comment: please share css as well

Comment: @NagaSaiA thankyou so much for pointing that out! i have made an edit to the post please review it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#right-panel #images-section #box-section").sortable({
            // Move when mouse pointer overlaps the other item
            tolerance: "pointer",
            // set cursor position in center
            cursorAt:{ top: $('.images').height()/2, left: $('.images').width()/2 },
            containment: "document",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use tolerance and remove containment and use helper:"clone"

```
$("#right-panel #images-section #box-section").sortable({
            cursor: "move",
            placeholder: "images-placeholder",
   tolerance:"pointer",
   helper: "clone"
        });
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yjNqGv

Use below options for tolerance

**"intersect"**: The item overlaps the other item by at least 50%. (Default tolerance)
**"pointer"**: The mouse pointer overlaps the other item.

check this link  - http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance

Comment: @uneebmeer, remove containment to see the difference

Comment: @uneebmeer, for smooth drag n drop , use helper:clone, updated answer and codepen

Comment: really sorry for the late reply @Naga , this was perfectly what i was looking for! just one last question before marking the answer can i control it? i have seen a property of draggable method named snaptolerance we can give it in px what happens is the snappping will occur when the 50px of the div is reached do we have something similar in sortable?